# don't know how to display data into the view (beginner)

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Good Morning everybody.

I'm a beginner in .Net languages and need an example to be able to go further.

So, my objective is to display dates and comments from a datatable, below general information about a client.

The view needs to become something like that :

name firstname :
adress :
phone number :
...

date1
comment1

date2
comment2
...

It was easy to automatically generate a strongly typed view with the general data. Now, I don't get how to display the comments below.

Here is what I've already done into the controller

```
    ' GET: /Contacts/Details/5

    Function Details(id As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim contact As contact = db.contact.Single(Function(c) c.idContact = id)
        Dim listMeet = New List(Of meeting)
        listMeet = (From d In db.meeting
                   Where d.FK_meet_contact = id
                   Select d).ToList()
        ViewBag.listeMeeting = listMeet
        Return View(contact)
    End Function
```

Into the view, I dis plenty of wrong things... Let's show you the last one :

```
@ModelType MvcApplication4.contact
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Details"
    Dim list As List(Of Object) = ViewBag.listeMeeting
    Dim ligne As ListItemCollection

End Code
```

[...]

```
<fieldset>
  <legend><button onclick="togglefield('Meet')">Meetings</button></legend>
    <div class="Meet">

     @For Each ligne In ViewBag.listeMeeting
         @Html.Raw(ViewBag.listeMeeting)
     Next (ligne)

    </div>  
</fieldset>
```

What haven't I well understood?

ps : I'm not a native english speaker, so, sorry if my english sucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a view model instead of `ViewBag`:

```
Public Class MyViewModel
    Public Property ContactDetails As Contact
    Public Property Meetings As IEnumerable(Of Meeting)
End Class
```

and then populate this view model in your controller and pass to the view for displaying:

```
Function Details(id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim contact As contact = db.contact.Single(Function(c) c.idContact = id)
    Dim meetings =
        (From d In db.meeting
         Where d.FK_meet_contact = id
         Select d).ToList()

    Dim model = New MyViewModel With {
        .ContactDetails = contact,
        .Meetings = meetings
    }
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

and then have your view strongly typed to the view model:

```
@ModelType AppName.MyViewModel

<h2>@Model.ContactDetails.SomePropertyOfContact</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <button onclick="togglefield('Meet')">Meetings</button>
    </legend>
    <div class="Meet">
        @For Each meeting In Model.Meetings
            @meeting.SomePropertyOfMeeting
        Next
    </div>  
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Very very great answer... It's 100% functionnal as it is. It's completely what I was needing.